# C# Android: googlemaps onclick get the lat and long

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I am looking for a way to get the lat & long when I click on the map. After that, add marker into that position. Here is my code:

```
    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-6.156445, 106.841790), 10));
        mMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(-6.156445, 106.841790)).SetTitle("Kino"));
        mMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(-6.166685, 106.728294)).SetTitle("OT"));
        mMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(-6.155592, 106.679585)).SetTitle("Mayora"));
        mMap.MapClick += delegate
        {
            //mMap.AddMarker here with pointed lat & long
        };
    }
```

Is it possible to set the lat & long into the title of the marker? If not, it's also OK to display it in a textview. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to get the latitude and longitude of a position clicked on your Google map, you can do this in the click event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});

});
```

For displaying the title/text in the marker, you can use [`infoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction).

The `InfoWindow` constructor takes an `InfoWindowOptions` object literal, which specifies the initial parameters for displaying the info window.

The content of the `InfoWindow` may contain a string of text, a snippet of HTML, or a DOM element. To set the content, either specify it within the `InfoWindowOptions` or call `setContent()` on the `InfoWindow` explicitly.

If you wish to explicitly size the content, you can put it in a `<div>` element and style the `<div>` with CSS. You can use CSS to enable scrolling too. Note that if you do not enable scrolling and the content exceeds the space available in the info window, the content may spill out of the info window.

For more information check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291938/how-to-display-text-when-tap-on-marker-in-google-maps-android).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do =>

```
mMap.MapClick += mMap_Mapclick;

mMap_Mapclick(object sender, MapClickEventArgs e) 
{
  LatLng clickPosition = e.Point;
}
```

You can get the Latitude & Longitude with the clickPosition ( clickPosition.Latitude, ...)